# java MainServer gives java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

Compiling is easy but when using java to run the programs, it gives `Exception found`. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 without internet connections. Also, installed Oracle JDK7 and JRE7. Also did the `update-alternatives` command on `java`, `javac` and `javaws`. Changed the machine java in `/etc/profiles`. `PATH` is pointing to oracle java folder. I did many searches on Google about this topic but each time jdk and jre version are different. Also check version of jdk and jre using java -version and javac - version. Both of them are the same. The system also contains OpenJdk6 and OpenJdk7.

So, how do I remove these errors? Java runs small programs but when using RMI gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you compile then run you code with different JDK/JRE versions: if compiling with JDK7, don't run with a JRE6 for example.

See [this thread on java.net](https://www.java.net/node/664117) or [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331138/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-myapp-unsupported-major-minor-version) for a detailed answer.